# Symfony2: How to have a form for an entity but with field not the same has properties

Tags: symfony

I have a Duo entity containing two persons. During the creation, the creator submits the email address partner and decides whether he is the captain or not of the new Duo. If he decides that he isn't (he choose the be the assistant) then, automatically, the second person is assigned captain. My Duo entity is as follows:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Duo{

    /**
    * @Assert\NotNull()
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="captain_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    private $captain;

    /**
    * @Assert\NotNull()
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="assistant_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    private $assistant;
```

I wonder how to organize my form so that there is only an email address that is submitted designating the partner. When I call `$form->isValid()`, I want my Duo entity to be valid. I do not want to use a form without entity because I do not want to have to assign data manually and handle errors outside of the form. Also, I would like to verify if one of the two users aren't involved in another Duo. If yes, how to pass the error message to the form in a clean way.

What should I do? Is there a way to do it using the Form Callbacks or Event or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Data transfers can do everything you want:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html

I suggest reading this very carefully, because it got very confusing the first time I did. There is a perfect example here that explains how to build `issue id` to `Issue`, basically same is your case.

As for the errors, I think your best option is to use `Callback` in combination with form `constraints` attribute:

http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/question-answer-day/custom-validation-property-path#creating-a-proper-custom-validation-constraint

You should probably read the whole article as there is not only "proper" way but "quick and dirty" as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok thanks for this. I took a look carefully at the doc on the data transformers and the only way I could is it is to applay a modelTransformer on the whole form which is said to be wrong. Also, I don't think it is a good way that a form helper (data transformer) can change the model of the app.